# The app crashes trying to create a videocall

Tags: flutter, mobile, agora.io

I cloned the project from Agora IO repository on github (https://github.com/AgoraIO/Flutter-SDK) and then I migrated it to androidX. The migration was okay, but when I try to create a channel the device show this error:

> An Observatory debugger and profiler on SM G9600 is available at:
>   http://127.0.0.1:53483/BBz2-lEt86o=/ For a more detailed help message,
>   press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q". E/flutter
>   (22196):
>   [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)]
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int
>   io.agora.rtc.internal.RtcEngineImpl.nativeLog(int, java.lang.String)
>   (tried Java_io_agora_rtc_internal_RtcEngineImpl_nativeLog and
>   Java_io_agora_rtc_internal_RtcEngineImpl_nativeLog__ILjava_lang_String_2)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.agora.rtc.internal.RtcEngineImpl.nativeLog(Native Method) E/flutter
>   (22196):      at io.agora.rtc.internal.Logging.log(Logging.java:25)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.agora.rtc.internal.Logging.i(Logging.java:49) E/flutter (22196):
>   at
>   io.agora.rtc.internal.RtcEngineImpl.checkIfInUIThread(RtcEngineImpl.java:155)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(RtcEngine.java:881)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.agora.agorartcengine.AgoraRenderViewFactory.create(AgoraRenderViewFactory.java:23)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.platform.SingleViewPresentation.onCreate(SingleViewPresentation.java:174)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:550) E/flutter
>   (22196):      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:391) E/flutter
>   (22196):      at android.app.Presentation.show(Presentation.java:267)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.(VirtualDisplayController.java:93)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.platform.VirtualDisplayController.create(VirtualDisplayController.java:53)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:105)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:96)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:60)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:231)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:93)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:642)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) E/flutter
>   (22196):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6990) E/flutter
>   (22196):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>   E/flutter (22196):      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
>   E/flutter (22196): F/flutter (22196):
>   [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)]
>   Check failed: CheckException(env). Lost connection to device.

Soemtimes it loses connection but the build happens, however the videocall "created" after that shows only a black screen. Don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: Have you passed YOUR APP ID in _initAgoraRtcEngine() method? moreover, also confirm that you have given required permissions.

Comment: UnsatisfiedLinkError - It looks like the Agora SDK is missing, have you enabled Proguard?

Answer (score 1):

The following can be the reason for the black screen:

1. You didn’t add the permission handler for the webcam and microphone
2. If you’re using an emulator make sure that you have defined the camera it needs to use in the settings.
3. Make sure you publish the stream.

You can refer to the sample code given over here: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Flutter-Quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you do not have permission for microphone and/or camera.